# Invalid SSL certificate on meta.*.stackexchange.com, can't log in without SSL

Tags: support, login, ssl

When I try to access `meta.*.stackexchange.com` via HTTPS, I get a warning:

> meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for the following names:
>
> *.stackexchange.com, stackexchange.com, meta.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, *.stackoverflow.com, stackauth.com, sstatic.net, *.sstatic.net, serverfault.com, meta.serverfault.com, superuser.com, meta.superuser.com, stackapps.com, openid.stackauth.com, *.meta.stackexchange.com
>
> (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

I'm using HTTPS Everywhere, but disabling it for Stack Exchange prevents me from logging in to the aforementioned meta sites—I simply get dropped back without being logged in (also, trying to ask a question causes a redirect loop).

Adding a security exception does work, though. Maybe this is because I'm already logged in to other Stack Exchange sites via a secure connection?

**Update:** It appears disabling the entry for Stack Exchange in HTTPS Everywhere then logging out and logging in again solves the problem of not being able to log in. See balpha's answer for details.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: ["Stackoverflow.com: the road to SSL"](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/).

Comment: Thanks, you might want to submit that as an answer. Here's the particularly interesting part: _What about meta.*.stackexchange.com? Damn. Can’t do that. You can’t have a wildcard of that form – at least not one supported by most major browsers, which means effectively it’s not an option._

Comment: Never mind, @balpha was faster with that. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once we officially support HTTPS, we'll probably move `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`. For details and reasons, see [Nick's blog post](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/).

Right now, HTTPS kind of works, but is purely for testing and not officially supported yet.

Comment: Thanks. It appears disabling the entry for Stack Exchange in HTTPS Everywhere then logging out and logging in again solves the issue.

Comment: And yet it doesn't seem possible to login through http on my phone due to automatic redirects.