# Signup button in "Thanks for the feedback!" dialog on meta.*.stackexchange.com redirect to the meta via HTTPS

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, sign-up

1. Visit any question on `http://meta.*.stackexchange.com/` without logged-in
2. Upvote that, you will get "Thanks for the feedback!" dialog
3. Click "Sign up using Email and Password"
4. Then redirected to `https://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/users/signup?...` and Chrome says "Your connection is not private"

It should be linked to the sign up page of main site, not the meta's.

[image]

Note: I know something may be broken [if I have visited via HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230302/286934), but **this problem also occurs on visiting via HTTP**. This is not HTTPS supporting problem.

Comment: This is one of the reasons SSL is not officially supported yet. See [this blog post](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) by Nick Craver for details.

Comment: @unarist Currently `http;//〜` is redirected to `https://〜` and HTTPS is officialy supported. So this problem seems to be resolved. Could you confirm that?